# Jmeter Plugin to Record Number of times Server/Web Page was Hit

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to create a Jmeter script to test an asp.net core application. The application acts as a load balancer that distributes request to other asp.net core app running.

I want to test the efficacy of the algorithm I used, so I am looking for how to get the number of times a user or request was sent to each of the load-balanced application.

Can I use Jmeter for this? If not what test can I do? I am using Jmeter because it will load test the application.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't know anything about underlying architecture of your application so it can give you only the number of the hits you made to the load balancer via [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/)

If you need to include the number of hits to each application which is behind the load balancer you might want to use something like [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which can either read the values from the file or execute an arbitrary shell command on the remote host so if you can expose the number of hits so Server Agent could consume it and plot the charts for each backend server behind the load balancer.

It also makes sense to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps/) to your test plan to avoid IP resolved IP addresses caching on JVM or OS level as under certain circumstances JMeter may hit only one IP address out of several

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please shed some light on exposing the number of hits from my application?

Also reading through the DNS Cache link you posted, the user used wireshark,, I am thinking that can capture the hit on backend servers. What do you think?